# Hide/Show elements on different domain

Tags: javascript, dns

Domain www.novameta.co.uk redirected to www.novameta.lt/en in iframe
When I load the page script is working. But when I go to next page script stops working. Is there any way to make script load again when I go to another page?

Script:

```
var loc = window.location;
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location)  // checks who I am ?
    ? document.referrer                          // If I'm frame give me parent url 
    : document.location.href;                    // If I'm static simple page, give me browser url
var elementLt = document.getElementById("left-side-lt");
var elementEn = document.getElementById("left-side-en");
var elementContLt = document.getElementById("cont-lt");
var elementContEn = document.getElementById("cont-en");
var elementLangs = document.getElementById("language-bar");
if (url.indexOf("novameta.co.uk") != -1) {
    if (elementLt != null) {
        elementLt.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (elementEn != null) {
        elementEn.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (elementContLt != null) {
        elementContLt.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (elementContEn != null) {
        elementContEn.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (elementLangs != null) {
        elementLangs.style.display = "none";
    }
} else {
    if (elementLt != null) {
        elementLt.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (elementEn != null) {
        elementEn.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (elementContLt != null) {
        elementContLt.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (elementContEn != null) {
        elementContEn.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (elementLangs != null) {
        elementLangs.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to handle this at the web server or reverse proxy layer if possible.

Comment: I made redirection to novameta.lt/en in frame for domain novameta.co.uk
The script is working. But when I go from HOME to CONTACTS (for example) script do not work any more. Is there any way to make script to load again after page switch?

Comment: Research .htaccess and mod-rewrite